# appium clicks on a not visible WebElement

Tags: java, android, jquery, selenium, appium

I have an android appium test for my android app.

My app has a webview with loader at start.

I have a link I want to click.
The link should lead to another web-page.

My android appium clicks the link
but because the loader is on foreground and not the link

It seems that appium already clicked the link but the page didn't change.

Is there a way to check a webElement is on the foreground? or other property I should wait for before clicking?

here is my code:

```
MyAndroidDriver myAD;


   myAD.changeToWebContext();
        myAD.changeToIFrame(By.name("braintree-dropin-frame"));
        WebElement element = myAD.waitAndGetElementBy(By.id("choose-payment-method"));
        if (element != null) {
            element.click();
            myAD.changeToDefaultIFrame();
            myAD.changeToIFrame(By.name("braintree-dropin-modal-frame"));
            while (myAD.waitAndGetElementBy(By.className("add-payment-method-link")) == null) {
                myAD.changeToDefaultIFrame();
                myAD.changeToIFrame(By.name("braintree-dropin-frame"));
                myAD.waitAndClickElementBy(By.id("choose-payment-method"));
            }
        }
        myAD.changeToNativeContext();
```

Comment: Can you share that page screenshot?

Comment: @Elad Benda : I also faced the same issue during one of my project work. The loader in our case was in WebView and regardless of trials we made, it could not switch to the webView. So the problem you are getting perhaps because appium is not switching to loader's WebView.

Comment: We managed to make it work, by removing loader from app for the sake of testing to proceed, as appium seems to have trouble with switching between multiple webviews. [This discussion](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/5089). @Helping Hands : Do we have any solution for this? I provided is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

i also faced same issue in one of my project,while i tried manually tapping in loader page  after few seconds the background page appears, so please try this case by manually if it works then

how to achieve this programmatically is following

1. `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`
   {This is to load background page to load}
2. `((AppiumDriver)).tap(int,int,int);`  {tap on loader page to enable the background page to get dispalyed}